# Handle multiple responses with ReplyingKafkaTemplate

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm trying to implement a reply response pattern in which I publish a message to a topic listened to by several consumer groups. That means that they will all get the message as well as submit the response in the reply topic.

The problem is because they all respond to the same message, only the first received message in the reply topic shall be answered. The others will be discarded. 
Given that I know how many responses I should be getting on the reply topic(call that number-n), how can I make ReplyingKafkaTemplate wait for n responses and then resolve the answer?
I've tried inferring from the [Spring Kafka documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#replying-template) but could not quite figure it out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That template is strictly for single request/reply processing.

You can't use it for your use case.

Use a `KafkaTemplate` and a separate listener; you will have to correlate the replies yourself.

**EDIT**

There is now an `AggregatingReplyingTemplate` for this use case: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#aggregating-request-reply

Comment: Also consider to study Spring Integration with its Scatter-Gather implementation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#scatter-gather

Comment: Would a reasonable approach be to extends ReplyingKafkaTemplate to have an implementation of onMessage and sendAndReceive to handle Map<correlationID, Collection<Future>>  instead of Map<correlationID, Future> ?

Comment: Yes, it would be a reasonable approach; but you probably don't need to change the send method; just make your `R` generic type a `Collection<Foo>`. But I was just looking at it and it probably needs some refactoring to make it easier to subclass; you might end up having to copy a bunch of code from onMessage. Of course, it would only work if you know how many replies to expect, unless you implement a timeout to return a partial result. Feel free to contribute it back to the framework if you think it might be of interest to the community.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I think I might have to copy the whole class as the onMessage accesses the private future class.
PS: Should I continue this discussion on github?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant about refactoring, to make it easier to subclass. Yes; please move to GitHub..

Comment: There is now an `AggregatingReplyingTemplate` for this use case: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#aggregating-request-reply