# Handle multiple responses with AggregatingReplyingKafkaTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-kafka

I am having a problem scenario to solve similar to that of 
[Handle multiple responses with ReplyingKafkaTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55168639/handle-multiple-responses-with-replyingkafkatemplate)

I understand AggregatingReplyingKafkaTemplate (using spring-kafka-2.3.7) can help solve this however, I am struggling to find the right bean configuration and get the an scenario where the I can aggregate the results from multiple consumers.   Following is my bean config, however,  I am getting compile error to say cannot resolve constructor for GenericMessageListenerContainer

```
    @Bean
    public AggregatingReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, Model, Model> replyKafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, Model> pf,
                                                                                     KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, Collection<ConsumerRecord<String, Model>>> replyContainer,
                                                                                     BiPredicate<List<ConsumerRecord<String, Model>>, Boolean> releaseStrategy) {
        return new AggregatingReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(pf, replyContainer, releaseStrategy);
    }
@Bean
    public GenericMessageListenerContainer<String, Collection<ConsumerRecord<String, Model>>>  replyContainer(ConsumerFactory<String, Model> cf) {
        ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties(requestReplyTopic);
        return new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, Collection<ConsumerRecord<String, Model>>>(cf,
                containerProperties);
    }
```

Any simple example how to use AggregatingReplyingKafkaTemplate will be helpful.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> getting compile error to say cannot resolve constructor for `GenericMessageListenerContainer`

Where? I don't see you trying to construct one.

Your `replyContainer` bean should return `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` given that is the declared type in the `replyKafkaTemplate` factory method.

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60384112/replyingkafkatemplate-kafkatemplate-not-sending-receiving-key) for an example.

It's easiest to use a `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` to create the container. If you use Spring Boot, it will automatically configure one for you; if not you will need to configure one as a `@Bean`